# How can i do async/await in AsyncStorage react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, asyncstorage

So, this is my index.js in react native projects

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import {
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  concat,
  ApolloProvider,
} from '@apollo/client';
import {setContext} from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: 'https://dev.saba.id/graphql'});

const getToken = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SESSION_TOKEN')
    .then(data => {
      if (data) {
        return data;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  console.log('------------');
  console.log('console.log inside getToken function');
  console.log('Bearer ' + token);
  console.log('------------');
  return 'Bearer ' + token;
};

console.log('------------');
console.log('output of getToken function');
console.log(getToken());
console.log('------------');

const headerLink = setContext((request, previousContext) => ({
  headers: {
    // Make sure you include any existing headers!
    ...previousContext.headers,
    authorization: getToken(),
  },
}));

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: headerLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Application);
```

Okay, now just focus in getToken function and also a console.log beside that function.

In my mind, when we use async/await the function will return after token variables is done to solve their result, am i right?

But what i get for the output is really confusing for me.. getToken function returning more fast then await AsyncStore value.

This is the output of the code :

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js 

 LOG  ------------
 LOG  output of getToken function
 LOG  {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
 LOG  ------------
 LOG  Running "sabaCustomerApp" with {"rootTag":61,"initialProps":{}}
 LOG  ------------
 LOG  console.log inside getToken function
 LOG  Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoic2FiYSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2FiYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlIjoic3VwZXIgYWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciIsImlhdCI6MTYyNzQ4ODY1MCwiZXhwIjoxNjMwMDgwNjUwfQ.W3vCNmIxsIyscJBk5aPMN3kqn7EVIEMLfZVgXqHB_UA
 LOG  ------------
```

Can you see? getToken() function retuning faster than console.log inside the function. How can it run like that?

What i want is, getToken() function returning a string such as "Bearer blablablabla"

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how async functions work.

When you call an async function, it actually wraps the function body in a Promise which gets returned:

```js
async function test() {
    await ...;
    return 123;
}

const promise = test();
console.log(promise); // Promise
promise.then(result => console.log(result));
// ^ logs 123 at some point
console.log('continue'); // runs before .then(...)
```

If you want your function to wait for a Promise to resolve, it also has to be async and use the `await` keyword:

```js
function waitSecond() {
    // This function isn't async, but still returns a Promise
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 1000));
}
async function otherFunction() {
    console.log(Date.now()); // x
    const result = await waitSecond();
    console.log(result); // 123
    console.log(Date.now()); // x+1000 (roughly)
}
```

I suggest reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and similar topics it mentions.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kelvin, but i'm really still confused about this honestly. I'm new in react native and javascript by the way.. if you don't mind, can you help me to fix the code i wrote? I really need your help..

Comment: I don't know Apollo, so I'm not sure how  to add async support to it, especially since you seem to need it synchronously. Perhaps you could create an async function `createApolloClient()` and while it's still loading, show a loading dialog to the user.

Comment: I mean, can you help me just for the function of getToken() ? so when i call console.log(getToken()); the code can give back the result like what token variables returning. If you can, i will really appriciate it

Comment: @VitoJuliano I suggest reading the article I linked. Since `getToken()` performs asynchronous stuff, you **can't** just "call it and immediately get the result". Your code calling `getToken()` will also have to be async with `await`, or use `.then` for callbacks.

Comment: okay thanks for the suggestion! Have a great day

Comment: @VitoJuliano If an answer was helpful enough, don't forget to mark it as the solution